# Asynchronous programming in Java/Guava

Tags: java, guava

```
class A{
    final B; 

    B.compute(); // Does executing this line create a new thread since this returns
    // a future and the entire function is executed by the same thread ?


    }

    class B{

    Future<Void> compute(){

    C obj = factoryOfC.getC();

    ListenableFuture<Void> future = executorService.submit (new Callable(){
        doSomething();
    });

    Futures.addCallback(future, new FutureCallback<Void>(){
        @Override
        void onSuccess(){
        }
        @Override
        void onFailure(){
        }

    } // end of callback. 
} // end of class B
```

How would you define a unit of work here ? Which thread/s will be doing which unit of work ? 
Would the callable and callback be executed in the same thread ?

WILL obj of type C be executed by the same thread ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you run it to see what it does? I doubt it because what you've provided won't compile.

Have you read the JavaDoc for the methods you are calling? The answers are there.

You submit a `Callable` to `ExecutorService.submit()`. The documentation for `Executor` says:

> The command may execute in a new thread, in a pooled thread, or in the
>   calling thread, at the discretion of the Executor implementation

... and the documentation for `ExecutorService` adds no specifics; meaning that as a programmer all you know is that you've requested that this be run in some thread, some time in future.

But you have a `Future` object that acts as a handle on the promised execution of your task. You use `Futures.addCallback()` to request that some work is performed when the task completes. In what thread will this work run?

The JavaDoc for `Futures.addCallback()` says:

> - If the input Future is done at the time addCallback is called,
>     addCallback will execute the callback inline.
> - If the input Future is
>     not yet done, addCallback will schedule the callback to be run by the
>     thread that completes the input Future, which may be an internal
>     system thread such as an RPC network thread.

Comment: Thanks. That helps. What about this question ? WILL obj of type C be executed by the same thread ?

Comment: There's no indication in your code that `obj` is a Runnable or a Callable. It gets constructed, but nothing else is done to it.

Comment: It is a non-thread safe object and there's addCount which gets called on it inside of doSomething().

Answer (score 0):

Not the execution of the line `B.compute();` alone creates a new thread; the line `executorService.submit` submits a new `Callable` to the `ExecutorService` which runs in a new thread.